# How do I check whether a set is a subspace over the modular numbers when said set is defined using integers?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, modular-arithmetic, vector-fields

Let $F$ either be $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.

For each of the following subsets of $F^3$, determine whether it is a subspace. Be sure to explain your answer.
$U_1=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in F^3: x_1+2x_2+3x_3=0\}$

I completed the $\mathbb R$ case, but I'm confused on how to approach the $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ case. In particular, how is $x_1,x_2,x_3$ a modular number when $U_1$ is define with integers 1,2, and 3?

I'm stuck here: Choose an arbitrary $(x_1,x_2,x_3) \in U_1$. We know $([0],[0],[0]) \in U_1$, since $[0] + 2[0]+3[0]=0$ ... wait but how is that possible ...? they're different types of numbers...?

Comment: I think this is an abuse of notation. Conventionally, if $F$ is a field then $F^n$ is viewed as a vector field over $F$. Without any statement about another base field, I would always assume that. Therefore the expression $x_1 + 2x_2 + 3x_3$ must be interpreted as if $1, 2, 3$ are in $Z/2Z$. As you note, $2$ and $3$ are not elements of $Z/2Z$, but it is easy to interpret $2$ as $[0]$ and $3$ as $[1]$. I assume that is what your example intends - that $U_1 = \{(x_1, x_2, x_3) \in (Z/2Z)^3 : x_1 + x_3 = 0\}$.

Comment: $\Bbb Z$ acts one every abelian group. Use $n\cdot  x:=\underbrace{x+\cdots +x}_{n}$

Comment: On the other hand, as Hagen von Eitzen points out, a "copy" of the integers can be identified inside of any field, as 1, 1+1, 1+1+1, 0, -1, and so on. I still regard this as an abuse of notation, because it interprets the "absolute" integers as relative to a particular field. But in the case of $Z/2Z$ its "copy of the integers" has $1 \to [1]$, $2 \to [1] + [1] = [0]$, $3 \to [1] + [1] + [1] = [1]$ and so on.

Comment: @preferred_anon thank you!